# What ARM instruction set does the Aquaris M10 support?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, arm, m10

I'm looking to install a few bits and pieces to do development work e.g. node but I need to know what instruction set the M10 supports to download/compile the right binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MediaTek MT8163B SoC in the Aquaris M10 uses the [ARM Cortex-A53](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A53) microarchitecture, which implements the [ARMv8-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#ARMv8-A) instruction set.

For Debian/Ubuntu repositories this corresponds to **arm64**, with GCC & qemu it's known as **aarch64**.

Answer (score 2):

It is not straight simple. While the processor is capable of **arm64**, and kernel is **arm64** / **aarch64**, the user-space is **armhf**!. It can be checked with simple command on M10 terminal:

```
apt-config | less
```

In my case on `frieza` it returned:

```
APT "";
APT::Architecture "armhf";
APT::Build-Essential "";
APT::Build-Essential:: "build-essential";
APT::Install-Recommends "false";
APT::Install-Suggests "0";
APT::Changelogs "";
...
```

meanning that apt (so and user space programs) use armhf.
While `uname -a` returns this:

```
linux ubuntu-phablet 3.10.93+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon May 23 10:51:39 UTC 2016 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

meaning kernel is arm64.

*update:*
after writing this answer I came across this: http://www.cnx-software.com/2016/04/30/setup-guide-mini-review-of-bq-aquaris-m10-ubuntu-edition-tablet-from-a-developers-perspective/

Comment: Can you please link sources for this information?

Comment: Interesting it would explain why my node js arm64  binary doesn't run, I'll have to compile a version for armhf and give it a go. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

UT tweek tool says this:

[image]

This may help identify, assuming it is correct. I have the M10 FHD.